# Kendo UI Waterfall chart negative data handling issue

Tags: kendo-ui, waterfall

Is there any way to draw x-axis at the bottom the chart in case or negative data provided to chart. Please have a look at attached screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Kendo has an option to set `axisCrossingValue` which may help you to achieve this.

Try the example: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-categoryAxis.axisCrossingValue

Set some very high negative value to `valueAxis.axisCrossingValue`.